# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Data.emp>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<User.Employee>'

Tags: c#

been stuck with this error for a while now.
basically i have 2 C# class library 
HeldDeskBusinessData and HelpDeskBusinessUser (shortened for the title)

from HelpDeskBusinessData

```
     public List<Employee> GetAll()
    {
        HelpDeskDBEntities dbContext = new HelpDeskDBEntities();
        List<Employee> employees = dbContext.Employees.ToList();
        List<Employee> busEmployees = new List<Employee>();

        try
        {
            foreach (Employee emp in employees)
            {
                Employee empBus = new Employee();
                empBus.Title = emp.Title;
                empBus.FirstName = emp.FirstName;
                empBus.LastName = emp.LastName;
                empBus.PhoneNo = emp.PhoneNo;
                empBus.Email = emp.Email;
                empBus.DepartmentID = emp.DepartmentID;
                empBus.EmployeeID = emp.EmployeeID;
                busEmployees.Add(empBus);
            }//end foreach
        }//end try
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }//end catch
        return busEmployees;
    }//end getallemployees
```

From HelpdeskBusinessuser contains an error (label)

```
    public List<EmployeeBusinessUser> GetAll()
    {

            EmployeeBusinessData empBD = new EmployeeBusinessData();
            List<Employee> empL = new List<Employee>();
            List<EmployeeBusinessUser> empBU = new List<EmployeeBusinessUser>();
            empL = empBD.GetAll(); /*error cant explicitly convert.  */
            try
            {
                foreach (Employee emps in empL)
                {
                    EmployeeBusinessUser empBus = new EmployeeBusinessUser();
                    empBus.Title = emps.Title;
                    empBus.FirstName = emps.FirstName;
                    empBus.LastName = emps.LastName;
                    empBus.PhoneNo = emps.PhoneNo;
                    empBus.Email = emps.Email;
                    empBus.DepartmentID = emps.DepartmentID;
                    empBU.Add(empBus);
                }//end foreach
            }//end try
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ErrorRoutine(ex, "EmployeeBusinessUser", "GetAll");
            }
            return empBU;
        }//end getallemployees
```

Anyone have an idea how to solve?

Comment: At what line does it throw the error in `HelpDeskBusinessData`? There is no `Data.Emp` class shown here anywhere. Is this a class you're using?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel: They've shortened it for the title.

Comment: @BobbyDigital: I wouldn't assume that, considering the namespace is also different.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel: I didn't assume it, that's what's said at the very beginning of the post. Unless of course I'm missing the point.

Comment: Ah gotcha, he made it a little riddle. The answer seems rather obvious: you're trying to create a list of `Employees` of one type and are retrieving a list of `Employees` of the other type. Explicitly define the namespaces and you're fine.

Comment: thank you for the quick response everyone. @JeroenVannevel I did shortened title since it will not let me post it if went over 150 characters. sorry, its my first semester on c# and i still get lost sometimes.. how can i explicitly define the namespaces?

Comment: Use `List<HelpDeskBusinessData.Employee>`.

Comment: i did have the declaration using HelpDeskBusinessObject and added the reference to HelpDeskBusinessUser

Answer (score 0):

If *UserEmployee* inherits from *Data.emp*, you can do a simple cast like this:

```
List<Data.emp> listDataEmps = empBD.GetAll();
if (listDataEmps == null)
{
    ... bummer ...
}

IEnumerable<UserEmployee> enumerableUserEmps = (IEnumerable<UserEmployee>) listDataEmps;
```

But if *UserEmployee* does not inherit from *Data.emp*, you can use the [System.Linq.Enumerable.Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.select.aspx) extension method together with a converter method:

```
IEnumerable<UserEmployee> listUserEmps = listDataEmps.Select(ConvertDataEmpToUserEmp);
```

*ConvertDataEmpToUserEmp* is a method for converting the *Data.emp* data type into the *UserEmployee* data type:

```
static UserEmployee ConvertDataEmpToUserEmp(Data.emp item)
{
    ... do the conversion here ...
}
```

You will have to implement this Converter method according to your requirements.

Note, that the Select method does not create a second list in memory, but only creates an enumerator iterating over the original source list.

If your scenario would require an independent List instead of an Enumerator depending on the source list (for example, a scenario where the source list might be modified by another thread while the enumerator traverses it), you could additionally call the System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList extension method:

```
List<UserEmployee> listUserEmps = enumerableUserEmps.ToList();
```

Side note:

Casting a generic collection type into another is not possible.
It doesn't matter if the collection type parameters inherit from each other or not.
If it were, you could do funny things like that:

```
List<FileStream> listFS = new List<FileStream>();
List<object> listSomeObjects = (List<object>) listFS;

double d = 42.0;
listSomeObjects.Add((object) d); // <<-- This obviously doesn't make sense...
```

Mind you, that this silly example also implies that the List<FileStream> object implements a method Add(object item), which, well, doesn't make sense either...

EDIT: I updated my answer in response to MarcinJuraszek's feedback.

Comment: Comment to the *side note*: you can do that with `IEnumerable<T>`, because it's set to be covariant. It's possible, because `IEnumerable<T>` does not expose any method modifying the collection. And you can do that with arrays of reference type, because of array covariance in .NET - but it will introduce runtime type checkes and make things much worse in performance.